# Run time input in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, popsql

I have  emp_table(table) having employee details.

The query goes as follows.

```
SELECT * FROM emp_table WHERE job = 'input()'
```

I have to give ***input at run time to select a certain kind of JOB*** details

my code was:

```
SELECT * FROM emp_table WHERE job = '&job'
```

It was giving a syntax error, I'm using POP SQL to write the code, so I don't know if the problem is with editor or if I'm doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Please post the full syntax error.

Comment: At quick glance at https://popsql.com/docs/getting-more-out-of-popsql/how-to-use-variables-in-a-query suggest your query format is incorrect and maybe you are not a premium team user.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not a premium user so I can't use it.